# How can I lock a model's associated collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locking, associations

I have

```
class Foo
  has_many :widgets
end
```

There's a place where I want to pull up all the widgets with a locked select. So, I want to do the equivalent of:

```
@widgets_to_work_with = Widget.find_all_by_foo_id(@foo.id, :lock => true)
```

With nicer code, something like:

```
@widgets_to_work_with = @foo.widgets(:lock => true)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could redefine the method widgets in Foo ActiveRecord or , safer ,add another method 
a.e.

```
# in Foo.rb
#...
def self.locked_widgets
  Widget.find_all_by_foo_id(self.id, :lock => true)
end
```

hope could be usefull